# Writing XML in loop c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

How would i write the xml out like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<calibration>
  <ZoomLevel 250>0.0100502512562814</ZoomLevel 250>
  <ZoomLevel 250>0.0100502512562814</ZoomLevel 250>
  ........
</calibration>
```

I know how to write it out but i cant write it out in a loop which i need to atm the i have for writting the xml sheet is

```
public void XMLWrite(Dictionary<string, double> dict)
{
    //write the dictonary into an xml file
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
    doc.AppendChild(docNode);

    XmlNode productsNode = doc.CreateElement("calibration");
    doc.AppendChild(productsNode);

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> entry in dict)
    {
        XmlNode zoomNode = doc.CreateElement("ZoomLevel");

        XmlAttribute ZoomLevel = doc.CreateAttribute(entry.Key.ToString());
        //XmlElement PixelSize = doc.CreateElement (entry.key = entry.Value.ToString());
        zoomNode.Attributes.Append(ZoomLevel);

        productsNode.AppendChild(zoomNode);
    }
    doc.Save(pathName);
}
```

Comment: <ZoomLevel 250> isn't a valid XML tag. What does your code output at the moment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the others said your wanted xml isn't valid. Another thing that I noticed is that in your example there are two nodes with the level zoom of *250* which is a key of the dictionary and as you know it should be **unique**.
However I recommend you to use **LINQ to XML** (`System.Xml.Linq`) which is simpler, so what about:

```
public void XMLWrite( Dictionary<string, double> dict ) {
   //LINQ to XML
   XDocument doc = new XDocument( new XElement( "calibration" ) );

   foreach ( KeyValuePair<string, double> entry in dict )
     doc.Root.Add( new XElement( "zoom", entry.Value.ToString( ), new XAttribute( "level", entry.Key.ToString( ) ) ) );

   doc.Save( pathName );
}
```

I tested this code by passing this dictionary:

```
"250", 0.110050251256281
"150", 0.810050256425628
"850", 0.701005025125628
"550", 0.910050251256281
```

And the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<calibration>
  <zoom level="250">0,110050251256281</zoom>
  <zoom level="150">0,810050256425628</zoom>
  <zoom level="850">0,701005025125628</zoom>
  <zoom level="550">0,910050251256281</zoom>
</calibration>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Michiel pointed out in the comments, the XML you want to create is not valid. As of the [W3C XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-Name):

> Almost all characters are permitted in names, except those which
>   either are or reasonably could be used as delimiters.

You might want to generate something like this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<calibration>
  <zoom level="250">0.0100502512562814</zoom>
  <zoom level="260">0.0100502512562815</zoom>
</calibration>
```

Generated with such a code snippet:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> entry in dict)
{
  var node = doc.CreateElement("zoom");

  var attribute = doc.CreateAttribute("level");
  attribute.Value = entry.Key;

  node.InnerText = entry.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

  node.Attributes.Append(attribute);

  productsNode.AppendChild(node);
}
```