# add element node to xml file c#

Tags: c#, xml

i am trying to add a new element to node which has attribute same with input. I tried, but i am beginning in xml. How can i do it ?

old xml file:

```
<Root>
 <Chatter Name="Dat" ID="1">
   <Content  Time="06/05/2014 2:00:08 PM">Send Content</Content>
   <Content  Time="06/05/2014 2:00:50 PM">Recieve Content</Content>
 </Chatter>
 <Chatter Name="Khang" ID="2">
    <Content  Time="06/05/2014 2:01:40 PM">Send Content</Content>
    <Content  Time="06/05/2014 2:02:00 PM">Recieve Content</Content>
 </Chatter>
 <Chatter Name="Khanh" ID="12">
    <Content Time="06/05/2014 2:03:10 PM">them moi</Content>
 </Chatter>
</Root>
```

i want to add a new element to node which has attribute Name="Khang" if it exist ,so here is new xml file

```
<Root>
 <Chatter Name="Dat" ID="1">
   <Content  Time="06/05/2014 2:00:08 PM">Send Content</Content>
   <Content  Time="06/05/2014 2:00:50 PM">Recieve Content</Content>
 </Chatter>
 <Chatter Name="Khang" ID="2">
    <Content  Time="06/05/2014 2:01:40 PM">Send Content</Content>
    <Content  Time="06/05/2014 2:02:00 PM">Recieve Content</Content>
    <Content  Time="06/05/2014 2:20:40 PM">Send Content</Content>
 </Chatter>
 <Chatter Name="Khanh" ID="12">
    <Content Time="06/05/2014 2:03:10 PM">them moi</Content>
 </Chatter>
</Root>
```

Thank you very much!
and my code

```
public static bool SaveMessage(string name, string content)
    {
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNodeList xmlnode,xmlOldNode;
        xmldoc.Load(_fileXmlPath);
        xmlnode =xmlOldNode= xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Chatter");
        for (int i = 0; i < xmlnode.Count;i++ )
        {
            if (xmlnode[i].Attributes["Name"].Value == name)
            {      
                XmlElement elem = xmldoc.CreateElement("Name", "Content", name);                 
                elem.SetAttribute("Time", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                elem.InnerText = content;
                xmldoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(elem);
                return true;
            }
        } 
        return false;        
  }
```

but it not add to xml file

Comment: you can used mentioned link [write a node][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931640/writing-xml-in-loop-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

As a rough example, the following should work for you;

```
//First load the xml into a XDocument (can be a string or file for example)
var doc = XDocument.Load(xml);

//Then try and retrieve the Khang node
XElement khang = (from xml2 in doc.Descendants("Chatter")
                    where xml2.Attribute("Name").Value == "Khang"
                    select xml2).FirstOrDefault();

//If the Khang node exists, create a new Element and add it to the Khang node         
if(khang != null)
{
    XElement newNode = new XElement("Node");
    khang.Add(newNode);
}
```

In detail:

1. First [load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the xml into a [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

   `var doc = XDocument.Load(xml);`
2. Then try and retrieve the Khang node using [Linq To Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387041.aspx) to select the Khang node

   `XElement khang = (from xml2 in doc.Descendants("Chatter")
                       where xml2.Attribute("Name").Value == "Khang"
                       select xml2).FirstOrDefault();`
3. Create a new [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.xelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it to the Khang node (if it exists)

   `if(khang != null)
   {
       XElement newNode = new XElement("Node");
       khang.Add(newNode);
   }`

Comment: i got it, it run exactly. thank you very much! Can you share me a website to learn about xml or gool tutorial ? i don't know start from where to have strong base.

Comment: @DatLieu Something like this appears to be a reasonable place to start: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=564